# Nunit3-console : Console.Writeln won't show up

Tags: nunit-3.0

I'm running nunit tests externally via Nunit3-console.
I'm not able to see any console.logs/console.Writeln

I find it mandatory to be able to track in real time, every step of the test.

I've read that nunit3 framework created a parallel test run feature, which is why the real time test output logs have been taken off.

But if I want to enjoy both worlds?
How can I trigger console logs during a test run?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunit3 framework doesn't support live hard coded console outputs when running tests from Nunit3-console, because nunit3 framework was meant to bring the parallel testing methodology, they found it pointless to allow such outputs when more than 1 test is running in parallel.

I solved this by downgrading to Nunit 2.6.4 which isnt supporting parallel testing and allows me to fire console outputs from my test.